# Routing using default template in reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, secretary

I am trying to use reagent to build my very basic project but I have a problem with routing and its parameter. This is from reagent looks like

**EDITED** - :require s added

```
(ns hammerslider.core
     (:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
               [secretary.core :as secretary :include-macros true]
               [accountant.core :as accountant]))     

;; Views

 (defn home-page []
   [:div [:h2 "Welcome to hammerslider"]
    [:div [:a {:href "/c/12"} "go custom"]]])

 (defn c [test]
   [:div [:h2 (str "on C " test)]
    [:div [:a {:href "/"} "go to the home page"]]])
```

I am trying to get `12` from `c` route which is the route handling is look like this

```
 (def page (atom #'home-page))

 (defn current-page []
   [:div [@page]])

 (secretary/defroute "/" []
   (reset! page #'home-page))

 (secretary/defroute "/c/:test" [test]
   (reset! page #'c)
```

[image]

I'm trying to catch the `test` parameter with the view function but it appears `on C`, not `on C 12`. How do I get to transfer the `test` parameter in to the view of `c`? or should I save it on different `atoms`?

**EDITED** - Mine solved by saving parameters into atom and it works, but is it the right way to pass the parameter?

```
(def parameter (atom ()))

(defn c []
  [:div [:h2 (str "on C " (:test @parameter))]
   [:div [:a {:href "/"} "go to the home page"]]])

(secretary/defroute "/c/:test" {:as params}
  (do (js/console.log params)
      (reset! parameter params)
      (reset! page #'c)
      ))
```

Comment: please try to change your atom to `reagent.core/atom`

Comment: @AlbertLai : thank you for the reply :).. I'm currently using `[reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]`

Answer (score 1):

It is depended on how you use your route parameters. The only guarantee between your program and reagent is if the value in ratom changed, the reagent component will be changed accordingly.

The TodoMVC is quite feature completed example for you to use `reagent` and `secretary`.

https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/reagent/src/cljs/todomvc/routes.cljs

By the way, most of the time I will use re-frame instead of using reagent directly.